# Get a column, modify, re insert into dataframe as new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I am pulling out a specific column with the index. I want to perform a split on that column and get the [1] value.

The column looks like;

```
Name
t_alpaha_omega
t_bravo_omega
d_charlie_omega
t_delta_omega
```

I need to split on _ and get alpha, bravo, charlie, delta. Then add those values as a new column in my dataframe.

I am getting the name column like;

```
final_df.loc[:,"Name"]
```

I can do the splitting, I just don't know how to insert the data as a new column.

I am playing with this and seeing if I can use a variation of it.

```
final_df.insert(1, "Test", final_df.loc[:,"Name"], True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose we could use [pd.Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and define a named capturing group like `(?P<New_Column_Name>...)`:

```
df['Value'] = df.Name.str.extract('(?P<Value>(?<=_)\w+(?=_))')
df

              Name    Value
0   t_alpaha_omega   alpaha
1    t_bravo_omega    bravo
2  t_charlie_omega  charlie
3    t_delta_omega    delta
```

If you would like to change the position of the column. We could first extract it with [pd.Series.pop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.pop.html) and the we insert it at the column index we would like:

```
new_column = df.pop('Value')
df.insert(0, 'Value', new_column)

     Value             Name
0   alpaha   t_alpaha_omega
1    bravo    t_bravo_omega
2  charlie  t_charlie_omega
3    delta    t_delta_omega
```

Comment: This is insane! I though it'd be way more complex. Thanks!! Can you set the column location kind of like you can with this `final_df.insert(0, "Value", '', True)`? I will accept your answer in 2min when it lets me.

Comment: Yeah it's not that difficult if you familiarize yourself a little bit with regex. You could also extract more groups (more capturing groups) resulting in more columns at the same time. With regard to the position of the column where do you wanna put it?

Comment: Position 3. Thanks so much! I learned something insane today!

Comment: I have added some edits. Since in this data sample we only have 2 positions I couldn't choose position 3, but you can do it in your data set.

Comment: You're welcome. Try to learn regex. It will give you lots of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below code helps.

```
newCol= [] 
for i in range(len(df)):
    a = df.iloc[i].to_list()
    requiredValue = a.split("_")[1]
    newCol.append(requiredValue)
df["newValue"] = requiredValue
```

It works perfectly for a string though.

[image: sample output]

Comment: This helps you to insert at a specific position in df.
`df.insert(loc = 0, column = 'ColumnName',  value = requiredValue)`

Comment: Thank you, I'd upvote if I had the karma. Thanks so much for responding!